# using xml2json with hebrew data

Tags: python, json, xml, python-2.7, hebrew

I'm trying to parse hebrew content from json to xml and from xml to json.
When I do that:

```
>>> from xml2json import json2xml
>>> json = {"test": "בדיקה"}
>>> json2xml(json)
```

I get the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
    json2xml(json)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml2json.py", line 182, in json2xml
    return ET.tostring(elem)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1126, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(file, encoding, method=method)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 820, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 937, in _serialize_xml
    write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1073, in _escape_cdata
    return text.encode(encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to encode and decode with utf8 but it doesn't seem to be working...
I'm using python 2.7

Comment: I assume it is the xml2json script itself, it returns `ET.tostring(elem)` which should be `ET.tostring(elem, encoding="utf-8")` ?!

Comment: What version of xml2json are you using? Did you install it with `pip`?  In my 2.7 environment, `pip install xml2json` installs a completely different xml2json.

Comment: To answer my own question, OP used `pip install https://github.com/hay/xml2json/zipball/master` from https://github.com/hay/xml2json

Answer (score 0):

Use a Unicode string, like so:

```
>>> from xml2json import json2xml
>>> json = {"test": u"בדיקה"}
>>> json2xml(json)
'<test>&#1489;&#1491;&#1497;&#1511;&#1492;</test>'
```

Comment: adding 'u' in the json content results in "Unsupported characters in input" error

Comment: @kitsuneFox - What "JSON content" are you talking about? Are you saying that when you cut and paste the three lines in my answer, you get a different result?

Comment: I say that when I create the json variable like you did in the second line I get this error

Comment: Ok  @Robᵩ , so I've tested it again, this time I wrote a script instead of using the regular python GUI. It works as expected. There is one more thing I'd like you to help me: when i take the xml result that is being returned from json2xml I'd like to make it json again using xml2json. When I do that I get the json with the unicode characters instead of the hebrew letters as follow: {"test": "\u05e9\u05dc\u05d5\u05dd"}...